# How to Calculate employee late coming and early going time using mysql query

Tags: mysql

when table is devicedetails includes intime,outtime,empcode,status.using these columns i want to calculate late and early going..if min(intime > 09:30:00) is late.if max(outtime < 18:30:00) is early going..mysql>

```
select * from devicedetails;

+-----+---------+----------+----------+------------+----------+--------+
| sno | empcode | intime   | outtime  | punchdate  | Lunch    | status |
+-----+---------+----------+----------+------------+----------+--------+
|   1 | 1001    | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | 2015-01-23 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|   3 | 1002    | 09:20:00 | 18:20:00 | 2015-01-23 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|   4 | 139634  | 09:00:00 | 19:00:00 | 2015-01-24 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|   5 | 160173  | 09:30:00 | 18:30:00 | 2015-01-10 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|   6 | 160173  | 11:30:00 | 17:30:00 | 2015-01-10 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|   7 | 160173  | 12:30:00 | 19:30:00 | 2015-01-10 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|   8 | 160178  | 10:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 2015-01-11 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|   9 | 160189  | 09:30:02 | 18:29:02 | 2015-01-12 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  10 | 160198  | 07:30:02 | 17:29:02 | 2015-01-16 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  11 | 160216  | 12:30:02 | 20:29:02 | 2015-01-17 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  12 | 160216  | 00:00:00 | 21:29:02 | 2015-01-17 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  13 | 160489  | 06:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 2015-01-17 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  14 | 160575  | 09:30:00 | 18:30:00 | 2015-01-18 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  15 | 160577  | 09:31:00 | 18:31:00 | 2015-01-18 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  16 | 160598  | 09:29:00 | 18:29:00 | 2015-01-19 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  17 | 161061  | 08:29:00 | 17:29:00 | 2015-01-20 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  18 | 1610612 | 07:29:00 | 14:29:00 | 2015-01-21 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  19 | 175064  | 07:45:00 | 15:35:05 | 2015-01-23 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  20 | 176261  | 07:45:38 | 15:35:59 | 2015-01-24 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  21 | 176374  | 06:56:59 | 17:35:45 | 2015-01-25 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  22 | 176374  | 00:00:00 | 12:35:45 | 2015-01-25 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  23 | 176374  | 13:00:00 | 00:00:00 | 2015-01-25 | 12:30:00 | P      |
|  24 | 176374  | 00:00:00 | 19:00:00 | 2015-01-25 | 12:30:00 | P      |
+-----+---------+----------+----------+------------+----------+--------+
23 rows in set (0.53 sec)
```

Iam using below query to calculate..but iam getting error as negative values and also wrong values..

```
select timediff(max(lasttimeout),min(first_timein)) tottime ,subtime((timediff(max(lasttimeout),min(first_timein))),'08:00:00') otime,ifnull(time_format(time_to_sec(subtime(min(first_timein),'09:30:00')),'%H:%i:%s'),'00:00:00') late,ifnull(time_format(time_to_sec(subtime('18:30:00',max(lasttimeout))),'%H:%i:%s'),'00:00:00') early from devicedetails where empcode='16715';
```

Plz help me....

Comment: Please add some Format to your Question

Comment: thank u for the  response..for example,if one employee intime  is 09:45:00 means we should calculate late coming as 00:15:00...because 09:30:00 is standard office time.. .this will be calculate on particular day.no need to find cumulative..it is the daily report..same in early going also..

Comment: yeah correct..it is the general shift...i mean shift timing is 09:30:00 am to 18:30:00..total working hours(8 hrs)..if any one work more than 8 hrs ,it will added in over time..so  i need to calculate late coming and early going..

Comment: So what does '00:00:00' signify? Did someone do a 19 hour shift?

Comment: it is not a problem to calculate late and early...19 hours means 11 hours added in over time.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
SELECT *,GREATEST(TIMEDIFF('09:30:00',intime),'00:00:00') early FROM devicedetails;
```

EDIT: It's not presently clear what it is that you want, but anyway the following query would return the overtime for each day, for each employee...

```
SELECT empcode
     , punchdate
     , MAX(GREATEST(TIMEDIFF('09:30:00',intime),'00:00:00')) early
     , MAX(GREATEST(TIMEDIFF(outtime,'18:30:00'),'00:00:00')) late
     , ADDTIME(
       MAX(GREATEST(TIMEDIFF('09:30:00',intime),'00:00:00')),
       MAX(GREATEST(TIMEDIFF(outtime,'18:30:00'),'00:00:00')) 
       ) overtime
  FROM my_table
 GROUP
    BY empcode
     , punchdate;
```

Comment: thank you so much..done some changes in your answer..it is working fine now..query is ##  select if(min(intime) > '09:30:00' , TIMEDIFF(min(intime),'09:30:00'),'00:00:00') late  from devicedetails;

Comment: Do you mean the first intime *per user per day*?

Comment: min(intime) is takes only very first intime for the day...multiple punches are there in a day..thats why we should take min(intime) and max(outtime)..because it is for general shift..it is not mach for alternate shifts..

Answer (score -1):

@strawberry

select if(min(intime) > '09:30:00' ,   TIMEDIFF(min(intime),'09:30:00'),'00:00:00') late  from devicedetails;